# App widget dialog from Activity not showing in redmi phones

Tags: android

i want to place widget to home screen from application using `requestPinAppWidget()` method.
`requestPinAppWidget()` open dialog in many devices for place widget to home screen but it not working in **Redmi** phones.

code for open app widget dialog

> appWidgetManager.requestPinAppWidget(myProvider, null,
>   successCallback);

Comment: i also try to solve this problem.

Comment: The same on xiaomi redmi 6a, but isRequestPinAppWidgetSupported returns "true"

Comment: Im encountering same issue with xiaomi devices. Seems it could be a launcher issue that could return true even if it should be false

Comment: MIUI's launcher doesn't show any infomation when invoking `AppWidgetManager.requestPinAppWidget` (except for their new MIUI widgets on MIUI 13). If your app has "INSTALL_SHORTCUT" (`com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT`) permission and it has been granted, it will be added, otherwise you will see a log (`E/AddItemActivity-PinShortcutRequestUtils: add widget failed, your.package.name has no permission.`) from launcher. You can still add widgets by `requestPinAppWidge` to launcher if "Lock Home screen layout" is enabled.

Comment: I have same problem, Has anyone solved it yet?

Comment: I have the same problem on POCO X3 NFC (MIUI 12.5, Android 11). Even logcat does not show any errors or any messages related to this issue

Answer (score 2):

Apps info on Redmi phones have a section of "Special permissions". One of those special permissions is "Home screen shortcuts".

requestPinAppWidget() on Redmi phones will add the widget only if this permission is on, and it will do it without showing a dialog for placing the widget.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem, I still not find a way to sove this officially.

there is a way to check requestPinAppWidge dose it work, maybe not a good way

as you know if requestPinAppWidge work, there has a dialog show, then activity will
onPaused.

1. So we just need call requestPinAppWidge.
2. And after some delay(Its important).
3. Check current activity status. If not onPaused, Give some tips.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32122165)